# Filling missing weeks of consecutive year with values

Tags: r

I want to insert missing weeks for each household_id, channel combination so that weeks becomes in sequence. The corresponding duration column will be inserted with 0 and other columns value remains same.

Below is the dataset.

[image]

For e.g. household_id 100 and channel A: missing weeks are 37,39 and 41. I want these weeks to be inserted and duration will be 0.

But For household_id 101 and channel C: Two years are involved, 2019 and 2020. Missing are weeks 52 of 2019 and week 3 of 2020.

what I tried is below using complete function

```
   library(tidyr)
   library(dplyr)
   temp <- data %>% group_by(Household_id,channel) %>% 
   tidyr::complete(week = seq(min(week),max(week)),fill = list(duration=0))
```

For Household_id 100 and channel A combination it worked fine. All weeks are now in sequence.
But for Household_id 101 and channel C it didn't worked. I want after inserting 52 week of 2019 it should go to 1st week of 2020.

I tried getting dates from week and year column thinking from exact date it may work
but not able to get that to work also.

```
data$date <- as.Date(paste(data$year,data$week,1,sep=""),"%Y%U%u")
```

Any help is greatly apprecited!

Here is the sample dataset with code:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 data <- data.frame(Household_id = c(100,100,100,100,101,101,101,101,102,102),
               channel = c("A","A","A","A","C","C","C","C","D","D"),
               duration = c(12,34,567,67,98,23,56,89,73,76),
               mala_fide_week = c(42,42,42,42,5,5,5,5,30,30),
               mala_fide_year =c(2021,2021,2021,2021,2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021),
               week =c(36,38,40,42,51,1,2,4,38,39),
               year = c(2021,2021,2021,2021,2019,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021))

  # imputing missing weeks and duration = 0 for each husehold channel combination
  temp <- data %>% group_by(Household_id,channel) %>% 
          tidyr::complete(week = seq(min(week),max(week)),fill = list(duration=0))

  # Getting Date from week/year if it may help 
   data$date <- as.Date(paste(data$year,data$week,1,sep=""),"%Y%U%u")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add the `year` in the `group_by()` then?

Comment: Even after adding year in group  by, week 52 of  2019 will not be considered. But of course it helps reducing weeks of 2020

Comment: Instead of going with `min(week)` and `max(week)`, why don't you manually declare 1 and 52?

Comment: can't do that because I just need the missing weeks in between. Declaring 1 to 52 will add all weeks of a year

Comment: For 2019 (Houshold: 101 / channel: C) you only have 51. So here you want to fill it with 1:51?

Comment: For Household 101/channel C missing weeks are 52 of 2019 and week 3 of 2020. Basically it would make the weeks in sequence. For Household 102 there are two weeks which are in sequence. So no missing weeks.

Comment: Ahhh ok, got it. Interesting. I ll give it a shot

Comment: My actual data is huge from 2019 to 2022. Some year have have 51 weeks other may have 53 weeks in a year. I feel extracting Date from year and week may help

Comment: I edited my answer to fill in the year and tidy up a bit. Let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining the dates, making the sequence and converting to weeks. I used `lubridate` for ease.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)


data %>% 
  group_by(Household_id,channel) %>% 
  mutate(new = paste0(year, '01-01'), 
         new = ymd(new) + 7 * week) %>% 
  complete(new = seq(min(new),max(new), by = 'week'), fill = list(duration=0)) %>% 
  mutate(year = replace(year, is.na(year), format(new, '%Y')[is.na(year)]),
         week = week(new)) %>%
  select(-new)

  Household_id channel duration mala_fide_week mala_fide_year  week year 
          <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1          100 A             12             42           2021    37 2021 
 2          100 A              0             NA             NA    38 2021 
 3          100 A             34             42           2021    39 2021 
 4          100 A              0             NA             NA    40 2021 
 5          100 A            567             42           2021    41 2021 
 6          100 A              0             NA             NA    42 2021 
 7          100 A             67             42           2021    43 2021 
 8          101 C             98              5           2020    52 2019 
 9          101 C              0             NA             NA    53 2019 
10          101 C              0             NA             NA     1 2020 
11          101 C              0             NA             NA     2 2020 
12          101 C              0             NA             NA     3 2020 
13          101 C              0             NA             NA     4 2020 
14          102 D             73             30           2021    39 2021 
15          102 D             76             30           2021    40 2021 
16          101 C             23              5           2020     2 2020 
17          101 C             56              5           2020     3 2020 
18          101 C             89              5           2020     5 2020
```